# How to find and edit front page

Tags: 7

I am new to Drupal and working for a customer. He wants me to change the title of the front page. I just cannot figure out how to get there. I have no problem with the rest of the pages on the site.

Comment: Barry, there's a *lot* of ways the <front> page could be built. Can you post a link to the site?  Odds are high that it's the Site Name field in admin/config/system/site-information if it's a "standard" site.

Comment: Or if a link to the site can't be posted, can you link to a screen dump image of the front page, with an arrow pointing to the element you want to change.  Knowing the name of the site's theme would also be useful.

Comment: you could also look at the template (tpl) files for the theme. If you can't find it elsewhere, it could be hardcoded

Comment: The website is http://appshosting.com/  the name of the theme is Innocompany

Comment: @Barry If `admin/config/system/site-information` doesn't help, you can also check if Metatag module (something like it) installed or not..

Comment: This was the solution ..the metatag module had a global front page option this is where I found the field to change the title...I removed [site:name] | [site:slogan] and added the new title

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to find the content of the variable `site_frontpage`.

You could:

1. `drush vget site_frontpage`
2. Use [devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) and it's variable listing
3. `SELECT * FROM variable WHERE name = 'site_frontpage';`

This will tell you where the frontpage is controlled from. Often it will simply be a node that you can edit.

Answer (score 0):

Just go inside currently enable theme
in template folder if available or in root folder where you have page.tpl.php
make copy of page.tpl.php rename to page--front.tpl.php
search "", comment out code.

login as admin-> clear cache under configration->performance

That's it!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I usually do:

1. Create a node for your frontpage, a basic page that will host your title and body content. Or find the current frontpage node if it's already created. Try searching for the current homepage title in your node content overview page (/admin/content/all)
2. Go to your site configuration (/admin/config/system/site-information) and change the default front-page to that node id or url alias if it has one (node/id or just the alias)

You will be able to edit the title on that node from now on. You might want to create your own template as well and you can apply this template after this step by creating a new page--front.tpl.php file in your enabled theme folder/templates, then clearing your cache. In that template, you can change the layout as much as you'd like and still use a node in the admin to edit the title and content.